# "I'm coming back home" equals to "I'm back home"?

Tags: difference

If someone tell me that he's back home *("I'm back home now")* does it mean that he's coming back home now or it means that he's already at home after some time that he wasn't there?

Comment: 'I'm back home' means he's _already_ (at) home.

Comment: I remember that someone talked to me on phone while he was a different country and he told me that he's back (but he didn't mention the word home) and what I understood from him then that he's **coming back** because he wasn't there yet.

Comment: Here's a definition of 'be back' from a dictionary: = to return (She left earlier but she should be back soon.) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20back

Comment: Thank you Alex for the reference, but does it not say the opposite of your first comment here, or you brought it to support your first comment?

Comment: Yes, it's in confirmation of what I said earlier. Probably, your friend omitted a word for a colloquial simplification or actually returned from a small trip to a hotel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

‘I’m back home now’ means they are already at home.

It can mean that they just arrived back into their house from a short trip to the supermarket, or it could mean that they arrived back in their country after a trip abroad. In both cases, it means that they already arrived.

However, it can mean, literally in their home (supermarket example) or just ‘somewhere in the country’ like - they could be in the airport (in the trip abroad example). They are ‘back home’ meaning - back home in their own country. The exact meaning of where ‘home’ refers to (literally in their home, or in their ‘home country’) depends on the context of what is being said.

‘I’m coming back home’ means they are on the way, and not home yet.

Examples - already in home:

- I’m back!
- I’m back home now!
- I’m home!

Examples - on the way back, not yet home:

- I’m coming back home
- I’m on the way back home
- I’m on the way back
- I’m coming back now